# what is really inside a picture and how to create one using C

Tags: c, graphics

I once saw someone create a picture using C, like this:

```
#ifdef _MSC_VER
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#endif
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

float f(float x, float y, float z) {
    float a = x * x + 9.0f / 4.0f * y * y + z * z - 1;
    return a * a * a - x * x * z * z * z - 9.0f / 80.0f * y * y * z * z * z;
}

float h(float x, float z) {
    for (float y = 1.0f; y >= 0.0f; y -= 0.001f)
        if (f(x, y, z) <= 0.0f)
            return y;
    return 0.0f;
}

int main() {
    FILE* fp = fopen("heart.ppm", "w");
    int sw = 512, sh = 512;
    fprintf(fp, "P3\n%d %d\n255\n", sw, sh);
    for (int sy = 0; sy < sh; sy++) {
        float z = 1.5f - sy * 3.0f / sh;
        for (int sx = 0; sx < sw; sx++) {
            float x = sx * 3.0f / sw - 1.5f;
            float v = f(x, 0.0f, z);
            int r = 0;
            if (v <= 0.0f) {
                float y0 = h(x, z);
                float ny = 0.001f;
                float nx = h(x + ny, z) - y0;
                float nz = h(x, z + ny) - y0;
                float nd = 1.0f / sqrtf(nx * nx + ny * ny + nz * nz);
                float d = (nx + ny - nz) / sqrtf(3) * nd * 0.5f + 0.5f;
                r = (int)(d * 255.0f);
            }
            fprintf(fp, "%d 0 0 ", r);
        }
        fputc('\n', fp);
    }
    fclose(fp);
        return 0;
}
```

What he have done is only putting a few number in the file `heart.ppm`. Only a few number, and he get an amazing 3D picture in photoshop, like this:[image]

So I was very curious that what is inside that `heart.ppm` file. But after opening it, I can only see a bunch of numbers, pure number. And then I open another `jpg` file, and see only a mess.

So, I was curious what is the magic here. Maybe only the format count. Maybe there is always only number and characters in a picture. But when using some tool (like photoshop) to open it, the tool would translate that message and then make it a picture for you.(Right?)

And I wanna ask,

1. How to make a photo like that using C ? You can't get a picture with only putting a few number in a file. There must be some standard to give those numbers a sense and make them consist of a picture.
2. what is the standard of those format ? `.jpg`, `.ppm`, `.png`, etc. any citation and related links?

Comment: This is a very very board question mate. Each format has different file formats. If you want to find out how each work technically, you will have to google each of them.

Comment: You are completely lost, you need to read about images and how they are represented digitally, and what RGB is and how you can store pixel values in the many available formats, and what a file format is ... So, a lot to study.

Comment: Note: that "standard to give those numbers a sense" is called mathematics and algorithms. And (as @iharob already stated) it takes a lot of knowledge to develop them and to implement them. However, you apparently have a very good motivation to learn.

Comment: short answer: raster images are arrays

Answer (score 2):

Broadly speaking there are two type of image file formats (answer to question #2)

1. Raster based
2. Vector based

**Raster based**

.jpg/.png/.ppm (and .bmp) are referred to as the Raster formats. In Raster formats, the color information for each pixel is stored. The image is stored as an array / a grid of Pixels. Color information is typically made up of 'RGB' - Red/Green/Blue. Typically, larger resolution or formats require more memory.

The 'C' code above generates the image as a Raster-based, those math functions are spitting out 'red' color. (answer to your question #1)

**Vector based**
.svg/.eps are typically the best known Vector formats. In Vector formats, there are commands that constitute the image. For example the image you showed above can also be represented potentially using following commands and many more

```
move-to (pos-x, pos-y)

draw-heart(<specify dimensions of the heart>, color,  <shading model details>)
```

and then a series of

```
concentric-circle(at-pos-x, at-pos-y, radius, line-thickness, biased-info-optional)
```

`draw-heart` and `concentric-circle` will contain a whole slew of other basic commands such as `line-to`, `fill`, and so on

It is a fascinating question that you ask - it has been a well-researched / discussed area.

Consider starting with this link
http://www.ed-brandt.com/pdfs/digital-graphics-primer.pdf